# Programming a Discord bot in Python- I have a meme command, how do I make it so there is less of a chance to show the same meme twice?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have a meme command for my bot. I've been trying to figure out how to make it less likely to show the same meme twice (it keeps repeating them). Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith(".meme"):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("cleanmemes")
    all_subs = []
    top = subreddit.top(limit = 75)

    for submission in top:
      all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = 0xffff00)

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await message.channel.send(embed = em)
```

Im new to programming, any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the memes' urls in a json or txt file. Then, you can check the new url with the sent ones.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith(".meme"):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("cleanmemes")
    all_subs = []
    top = subreddit.top(limit = 75)

    for submission in top:
      all_subs.append(submission)
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
        with open('urls.txt', 'r+') as file:
        if url in file.read():
            return
        else:
            file.write(f'{url}\n')
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = 0xffff00)

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await message.channel.send(embed = em)
```

In this code, you must create a `urls.txt` file at first. Then, it will check the url's of the memes that you've sent before. If it has sent before, it'll return and won't send anything. If it doesn't, it will save it to that txt file and will send the meme.

Comment: So would I have manually put the url into that file every time it sends a meme?

Comment: No, you just have to create a txt file named `urls.txt` in the same folder with the py file. Then code will do the rest.

Comment: Oh and one more thing: it works now, there are no repeats. For the most part. Several times now I found that there is two of the same URL in urls.text, anything I can do about that?

Comment: I don't know how it could happen.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. Guess I'll just have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try storing a list of the memes that you've already sent (i.e. a list of URLs) and check whether the URL is in your list before sending the message?

Pseudo-code example, below.

```
# at the beginning of your code initialize an empty list of memes
sent_memes = []

# check if meme has been sent - skip if so
if url in sent_memes:
    pass

else: 
    # send meme
    sent_memes.append(url) # add url to list of sent_memes
```

This approach would ensure that you never send two of the same memes (unless they have different URLs).